# Jackson 2.6.3 Deserialization avoid literal null added to collection

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a json context using Jackson 2.6.3. I have null literal in json content as below. I am trying to avoid that being added to the deserialized collection. See the output below. I tried various configuration options on the mapper. However I am unable to avoid null object in the collection. Any pointers to resolve the issue welcome.

I have seen many similar questions in stackoverflow like the one below, but all of them related to custom deserializing individual attributes in a class, but not an element in a collection.

[How to deserialize JSON null to a NullNode instead of Java null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293697/how-to-deserialize-json-null-to-a-nullnode-instead-of-java-null)

JSON Content (Data.txt)

```
{
  "myList": [
  {
     "type": "1"
  },
  {
     "type": "2"
  },
  null
  ]
}
```

RootObject.java

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class RootObject {

private List<Types> myList;

public List<Types> getMyList() {
    return myList;
}

public void setMyList(List<Types> myList) {
    this.myList = myList;
}

public String toString(){
    return new ReflectionToStringBuilder(this).toString();
}
}
```

Types.java

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Types {

private String type;

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String toString(){
    return new ReflectionToStringBuilder(this).toString();
}
}
```

JacksonTester

```
public class JacksonTester2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.getSerializationConfig().withSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);
        RootObject rootObject = null;
        try {
            rootObject = mapper.readValue(new File("Data.txt"), RootObject.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        System.out.println(rootObject);
    }
    }
```

Output

```
RootObject@1a74681a[myList=[Types@ace10d9[type=1], Types@5eb41c19[type=2], null]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an inspiration from the following post

[Jackson: Ignore whitespace in empty @XmlWrapperElement collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397419/jackson-ignore-whitespace-in-empty-xmlwrapperelement-collection)

Here is the solution specific to the question above

```
public class NullCollectionHandler extends SimpleModule {
    private static class CustomizedCollectionDeserialiser extends CollectionDeserializer {

        public CustomizedCollectionDeserialiser(CollectionDeserializer src) {
            super(src);
        }

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Collection<Object> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            Collection<Object> oldCol = super.deserialize(jp, ctxt);
            Collection<Object> newCol = new ArrayList<Object>();
            if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(oldCol)){
                for(Object obj : oldCol){
                    if(obj != null)
                    newCol.add(obj);
                }
            }
            return newCol;
        }

        @Override
        public CollectionDeserializer createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt,
                BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
            return new CustomizedCollectionDeserialiser(super.createContextual(ctxt, property));
        }
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
        super.setupModule(context);
        context.addBeanDeserializerModifier(new BeanDeserializerModifier() {
            @Override
            public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyCollectionDeserializer(
                    DeserializationConfig config, CollectionType type,
                    BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {
                if (deserializer instanceof CollectionDeserializer) {
                    return new CustomizedCollectionDeserialiser(
                        (CollectionDeserializer) deserializer);
                } else {
                    return super.modifyCollectionDeserializer(config, type, beanDesc,
                        deserializer);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. I just needed minimal tweaking to call trimToSize() on deserialized ArrayList instances to save memory when deserializing big json data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly modify things in that way for array deserialization. But a relatively simple way may be to define a `Converter` that takes `Collection` (or `List`) of expected type, returns the same, and use:

```
@JsonDeserialize(converter=MyConverter.class)
```

to indicate that it should be used as part of deserialization. What this would do is let Jackson deserialize `Collection` using default logic, and then your converter can iterate through it and remove `null` entries (or create a new `Collection` if you prefer).

Alternatively you could create a custom `Collection`/`List` subtype, and override its `add()` method to silently drop `null`s, but pass other values via `super.add(value)`. This would be the most efficient method, and perhaps even simplest.
You could even declare property type to still be simple `Collection`, but specify subtype to actually use with:

```
@JsonDeserialize(as=NoNullsCollection.class)
public List<String> names;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can configure your ObjectMapper to ignore NULLs like this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

Or you can make use of the following annotation:

```
@JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
```

Comment: question is about DEserialization

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky yeah sorry my bad I've missed that bit :|